# issues with creating varchar returning functions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an issue while creating functions in sql server, am very new to sql server
Below mentioned is the code which i used, please any issues with syntax.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Fn_Check_Customer_Credit (@AcctCode VARCHAR(20), @CurrentAmount NUMERIC(20,2), @CurrentDate DATETIME, @CompCode VARCHAR(20), @CurrentUser VARCHAR(20)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Str_Block_Limit     VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @Str_Check_Days      VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @Str_Acct_Lock       VARCHAR(10)
  DECLARE @Str_Return          VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @Num_Credit_Limit    NUMERIC(20,8)
  DECLARE @Num_Credit_Days     NUMERIC(20,8)
  DECLARE @Num_Current_Credit  NUMERIC(20,8)
  DECLARE @Num_Total_Pending   NUMERIC(20,8)
  DECLARE @Num_Temp            INT
  DECLARE @Num_CurrentBal      NUMERIC(20,8)

  SELECT @Num_Temp = COUNT(*) FROM GN_USER_SETTINGS_DETAIL WHERE USER_NAME = @CurrentUser AND SETUP_CODE = 3;  -- Credit Limit Exception
  SELECT @Str_Block_Limit = CONFIG_VALUE FROM GN_ELIXIR_CONFIG WHERE CONFIG_NAME = 'BLOCK_CUSTOMER_CREDIT_LIMIT' AND COMP_CODE = @CompCode;     
  SELECT @Num_Credit_Limit = CREDIT_LIMIT, @Num_Credit_Days = CREDIT_DAYS, @Str_Acct_Lock = LOCK_ACCT FROM AC_SL_MASTER WHERE ACCT_CODE = @AcctCode;
  SELECT @Num_CurrentBal = (SUM(A.AMOUNT) + SUM(A.DN_AMOUNT))  
            FROM (SELECT SUM(ISNULL(DOC_BALANCE, 0)) AMOUNT, 0 DN_AMOUNT 
                  FROM Fn_Aging(@CurrentDate,@CompCode,@AcctCode)
                  UNION ALL 
                  SELECT SUM(ISNULL(ITEM_QTY, 0) * ISNULL(ITEM_RATE, 0) - ISNULL(DISCOUNT, 0)) AMOUNT, SUM(ISNULL(ITEM_QTY, 0) * ISNULL(ITEM_RATE, 0) - ISNULL(DISCOUNT, 0)) DN_AMOUNT
                  FROM VW_PENDING_DNOTE 
                  WHERE ACCT_CODE = @AcctCode) A;
  IF @Str_Acct_Lock = 'Y'  -- CURRENT CUSTOMER IS LOCKED.
    RETURN 'Account is Locked';
  IF @Str_Block_Limit = 'N'  -- NO NEED TO CHECK THE CREDIT LIMIT.
    RETURN NULL;

  IF ISNULL(@Num_Temp, 0) > 0  -- CUSER IS ALLOWED TO ENTER BEYOND THE CREDIT LIMIT OF THE CUSTOMERS.
    RETURN NULL;
  IF (@Num_Credit_Limit  0)  ---- CURRENT CREDIT IS GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO THE CREDIT LIMIT.
    RETURN 'Credit Limit Exceeded.';
  ELSE 
    RETURN '0';
END;
```

Comment: How about including the error message you get?

Comment: At least something missing from here: `(@Num_Credit_Limit  0)`

Comment: Error message is:  The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx):

```
      --Transact-SQL Scalar Function Syntax  
CREATE FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name   
( [ { @parameter_name [ AS ][ type_schema_name. ] parameter_data_type   
    [ = default ] [ READONLY ] }   
    [ ,...n ]  
  ]  
)  
RETURNS return_data_type  
    [ WITH <function_option> [ ,...n ] ]  
    [ AS ]  
    BEGIN   
        function_body   
        RETURN scalar_expression  
    END  
[ ; ]
```

So, the return statement must be the last one. Use a variable to store your return value and add in the end return @retval.

Comment: I assigned all return values to @Str_Return variable, then its giving error  :Incorrect syntax near '@Str_Return'.

Comment: You fixed the missing operator in the if clause? Edit your question with the latet code, otherwise it's quite difficult to figure out what's wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by changing 
Use the below code to resolv the issue.

```
DECLARE @ReturnVal varchar(100) 

  IF (@Num_Credit_Limit  0)  ---- CURRENT CREDIT IS GREATER THAN OR EQUAL TO THE CREDIT LIMIT.
    SELECT @ReturnVal = 'Credit Limit Exceeded.';
  ELSE 
    SELECT @ReturnVal = '0';

   RETURN @ReturnVal
```

Comment: That's the solution provided by @JamesZ.